# Not able to detect face features when image from ImagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, face-detection

I am using `CoreImage` framework of IOS for the face detection. The sample code works fine. But when I load the image from the `ImagePicker` from the photo library, then it do not do the correct face detection.
Here is the code I use for face detection :

```
-(void)openCamera

{
    picker_ = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker_.delegate = (id)self;
    picker_.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [self presentViewController:picker_ animated:YES completion:nil];
    picker_=nil;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imgVw_User.image =    [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self faceDetector];
}

-(void)faceDetector
{
    // Draw the face detection image
    [self.view addSubview:imgVw_User];

//     imgVw_User.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"73_Before_Fractional_Skin_Resurfacing.jpg"];

    // Execute the method used to markFaces in background
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(markFaces:) withObject:imgVw_User];

    // flip image on y-axis to match coordinate system used by core image
    [imgVw_User setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];

    // flip the entire window to make everything right side up
    [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
}

-(void)markFaces:(UIImageView *)facePicture
{
    // draw a CI image with the previously loaded face detection picture
    CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:facePicture.image.CGImage];

    // create a face detector - since speed is not an issue we'll use a high accuracy
    // detector
    CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                              context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

    // create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector
    NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

    // we'll iterate through every detected face.  CIFaceFeature provides us
    // with the width for the entire face, and the coordinates of each eye
    // and the mouth if detected.  Also provided are BOOL's for the eye's and
    // mouth so we can check if they already exist.
    for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
    {
        // get the width of the face
    `CGFloat faceWidth = faceFeature.bounds.size.width;`

    `// create a UIView using the bounds of the face`
    `UIView* faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFeature.bounds];`

    // add a border around the newly created UIView
    faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    // add the new view to create a box around the face
    [self.view addSubview:faceView];

    if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)
    {
        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
        UIView* leftEyeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.leftEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.leftEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
        // change the background color of the eye view
        [leftEyeView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
        // set the position of the leftEyeView based on the face
        [leftEyeView setCenter:faceFeature.leftEyePosition];
        // round the corners
        leftEyeView.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;
        // add the view to the window
        [self.view addSubview:leftEyeView];
    }

    if(faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition)
    {
        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
        UIView* leftEye = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.rightEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.rightEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
        // change the background color of the eye view
        [leftEye setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
        // set the position of the rightEyeView based on the face
        [leftEye setCenter:faceFeature.rightEyePosition];
        // round the corners
        leftEye.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;
        // add the new view to the window
        [self.view addSubview:leftEye];
    }

    if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
    {
        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
        UIView* mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.mouthPosition.x-faceWidth*0.2, faceFeature.mouthPosition.y-faceWidth*0.2, faceWidth*0.4, faceWidth*0.4)];
        // change the background color for the mouth to green
        [mouth setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
        // set the position of the mouthView based on the face
        [mouth setCenter:faceFeature.mouthPosition];
        // round the corners
        mouth.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.2;
        // add the new view to the window
        [self.view addSubview:mouth];
    }
 }
}
```

If I change the image which comes from the `imagePicker` to a static image within the application, i.e `73_Before_Fractional_Skin_Resurfacing.jpg` , then the detection is correct. The problem comes when the image is from the photo library, i.e from `ImagePicker`.
Please advice..

Comment: have you checked the actual image from imagePicker? What is generatePhotoThumbnail doing? If you save an image from imagePicker, then reload it manually as a static image, is that ok?

Comment: @HeWas - Tha was a little experiment from me. Even if i use exact image, It does not work..

Answer (score 4):

Might be this code will help you, Use Image returned by this function

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image {
static int kMaxResolution = 640;

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;
CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
    } else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;

UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation
            (imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation
            (imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;
    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
            format:@"Invalid image orientation"];
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
} else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}
CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *returnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: how can I crop only face according your algorithm?